# Compile under Windows CMD , but not under Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I've been configuring Eclipse+CDT+Cygwin for a long time.Recently I've made sure that by typing make in CMD under the path `workspace\project\debug` the whole toolchain (make , g++ , etc) works pretty well.But in Eclipse it always shows `"Cannot run program "make": ?????????¨?"`.

Here is the information shown in CMD after typing make

> C:\Users\llz\workspace\test\Debug>make
>
> Building file: ../test.cpp
>
> Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
>
> g++ -I"C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.5.3\include\c++" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"test.d" -MT"test.d" -o "test.o" "../test.cpp"
>
> Finished building: ../test.cpp
>
> Building target: test.exe
>
> Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
>
> g++ -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/ -o "test.exe"  ./test.o
>
> Finished building target: test.exe

What's more,often Eclipse can't understand the symbol *std*.It shows `'std' is ambiguous '`.So,symbols like *cout* and *endl* can't be resolved.